# How can I run an exe file on Windows Azure that receive, process and feed data to a Windows Phone mobile app?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, mobile, windows-phone-8.1, mobile-application

I want to create a Windows Phone mobile app that receive inputs, send the inputs to an exe running continuously on Windows Azure to process and send outputs back to the mobile app. I have the knowledge to create a WP apps but little experience in Azure ,though I have access to it, so I don't know which service to use and how to use it. Please help

Comment: Try looking into Mobile Services. It's basically an ASP.NET application with a backend database that exposes public REST API uris for your app to use. If you can convert the .exe to code that can run on the mobile service server than it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could [run an .exe in a web role on Azure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331425/Running-an-EXE-in-a-WebRole-on-Windows-Azure) but there might be a better, and easier, way to architect your solution.

Consider using [Azure Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/mobile-services/) and, as WiteCastle says, re-architect your exe into a custom web API. Here are some examples of [RESTful Web API projects](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/aspnet-web-api) from Microsoft's [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net) site.

Here are some useful resources to get you started:

- Learn how to build secure mobile apps for the enterprise: [view
  webinar](https://azureinfo.microsoft.com/CO-Azure-WBNR-FY15-10Oct-BuildingSecureMobileAppsintheEnterprise-Registration-Page.html)
- Learn how to build consumer mobile apps that scale: [view webinar](https://azureinfo.microsoft.com/CO-Azure-WBNR-FY15-10Oct-BuildingConsumerMobileAppsthatScale-Registration-Page.html)
- Choosing the best backend for your mobile app: [view webinar](https://azureinfo.microsoft.com/CO-Azure-CNTNT-FY15-09Sep-Choosingthebestbackendforyourmobileapp-Registration-Page.html)

**Alternatively...**

If you're more comfortable with a web based back-end, why not try a product like [appery.io](https://appery.io/), which allows you to create and connect up your app all via a 100% browser based IDE.